# wordpress update multiple posts post meta

Tags: post-meta

I am trying to update multiple posts post meta at the same time. I have the following query:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php 

$variations = new WP_Query();   
$variations->query(array('showposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'product_variation' )); while ($variations->have_posts()) : $variations->the_post(); ?>

<input name="regular_price[]" type="text" value="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(), "_regular_price", true); ?>" />
<input name="sale_price[]" type="text" value="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(), "_sale_price", true); ?>" />
<input name="item_id[]" type="hidden" value="<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>" />

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?> 
<input name="save" type="submit" />
```

I then have the following php to process the data:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {

    $ids = $_POST['item_id'];
    $sales = $_POST['sale_price'];

foreach ($ids as $id){

    update_post_meta($id,'_sale_price',$sale));

}
} ?>
```

For some reason the above does not save correctly. It will only save the last value, and apply this to all post meta. Is there something i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because there is no relationship between the item id and the price when you are collecting the posted data. Do the changes as below.

Change the sale_price to below to include the item id

```
<input name="sale_price[<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>]" type="text" value="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_id(), "_sale_price", true); ?>" />
```

Then change the loop for collecting the data as below.

```
foreach ($ids as $id){
    update_post_meta($id,'_sale_price', $sales[$id]);
}
```